# How does block retain variables in non ARC environment?

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I maintain some legacy codes that implemented in non ARC environment. Are there any memory management problems in the following code snippet? (That is, `tImage` is retained in the block and will never be released.)

```
+ (void)noCacheImageWithName:(NSString *)name completion:(imageload_block_t)imageLoadBlock
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        UIImage *tImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:<#image_path#>];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            imageLoadBlock(tImage);
        });
    });
}
```

**UPDATE**

The `block` I mentioned in the code snippet is the `block` in the main queue.

Comment: you seem to be misunderstanding why blocks can cause retain cycles. Your `tImage` does hold a reference to the block, does it?

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant I think the block is the `NSConcreteStackBlock` type and is not retained by `tImage`. When using `tImage` in the block, `tImage`'s reference count is increased, but there isn't a corresponding release operation.

Comment: If `tImage` doesn't reference the block then there's no possibility for a retain cycle. "there isn't a corresponding release operation" – which is a good thing. `tImage` isn't created by `new` or `alloc`, so it's autoreleased – it **MUST NOT** be released explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

`dispatch_async()` will copy the block that is passed to it, because it needs that block to survive the caller's scope. The block captures the value of `tImage`. So, when the block is copied, it retains the pointed-to `UIImage` object.

Of course, GCD will ensure that the copy of the block will be released after it has executed. When that block is deallocated, it will release anything it retained. That includes the `UIImage` object that `tImage` pointed to.

So, everything is balanced as far as what `dispatch_async()`, GCD, and the block runtime do is concerned.

Assuming that `imageLoadBlock()` is well-behaved in terms of memory management, there are no problems with that code.